# Docker commands fails (in Windows)

Tags: docker

I am trying to use Docker on a windows machine and is hit with every possible issue it seems. My latest one is this:
My machine is running but I can't seem to interact with it using the docker commands. If I run a very standard command like:

```
docker ps
```

I get an error message like this:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v
1.23/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So apparently some path is all messed up. Do anyone know which path this is and how to fix this?

Comment: In tray Docker is running, however in Docker->Settings is status: unable to start. Click to Restart Docker fixes error

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 60):

**Edit** (2021) - This answer is for the old Docker Toolbox, not Docker Desktop.

When running `docker ps` and receiving:

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

The following environment properties need to be set:

```
 set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
 set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
 set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
 set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

This is assuming the `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default` is default path where the `cert.pem`, `key.pem`, `ca-key.pem`, and `ca.pem` docker files are; the virtual machine name's (created by `docker-machine create`) is `default` and Virtual Box DHCP Server's lower bound (found under VirtualBox->File->Preferences->Network->Host-only Networks->hover mouse on VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter) is 192.168.99.100 and no other VM is running in VirtualBox.

Comment: thanks, that works for me, but i have to run these commands every time i open my command prompt. Is there any way i can set the values permanently.

Comment: Does [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) help?

Comment: After setting the parameters, I am getting following message: An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://xxx.xx.xx:2376/v1.24/imag
es/create?fromImage=hello-world&tag=latest: dial tcp xx.xxx.xx.xx:2376: connec
tex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly re
spond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
 host has failed to respond. Where xxx is the lower bound.

Comment: If you execute `docker-machine env --shell cmd` it will show these instructions, as well as a copy-paste-able shorthand to run them

Comment: @TechTurtle you need to set your proxy

Comment: Wow I already like Vagrant better. None of that is required for Vagrant. And none of that is even mentioned in the documentation! https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#prepare-your-docker-environment

Comment: `>dir %USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: @jan.supol, does this apply to Docker for Windows (as well as Docker Toolbox).  Does the installation process not set these variables? I have asked a similar question here and would be grateful for an answer from you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465944/cannot-switch-from-linux-container-to-windows-container +1.

Answer (score 19):

Same issue here on Win 7. Solution:

In the Docker Quickstart window, at the $ prompt run the below line:

> your_user@your_machine MINGW64 ~
>
> $ eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env default)

Then, you'll be able to run "docker run hello-world".

Answer (score 17):

I run into this problem when using docker-machine and I haven't run the `docker-machine env` command after rebooting. I'm not sure how to do this in cmd.exe, but if you're using powershell try issuing this command:

```
docker-machine env --shell=powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

Comment: This worked for me, do we know why it solves this problem?  I used to not have but I think an MS update broke Docker.  I'd like a permament solution.

Comment: @hamsterofdark `docker-machine env` displays the command to configure your shell to use the Docker client, whatever the shell is (it tries to detect the shell automatically if you don't include the `shell` parameter). Aurath's answer immediately invokes the returned command.

Comment: `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`

Answer (score 10):

Make sure Hyper-V is up and running:

- open elevated command prompt
- type `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
- reboot
- run "Docker for Windows"

Comment: To clear up some confusion: installation of docker on Windows has two versions: "Docker Toolbox" (Older version, uses VirtualBox) and "Docker for Windows" (Newer version, uses native Hyper-V). 
If you're running Docker Toolbox, see other answers. 
If you're running Docker for Windows, use this answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had to deal with the same issue on Windows.

To solve it:

1. Create a docker machine (only if you have not got one)

   ```
   docker-machine create  default
   ```
2. Get the ENV vars which the docker client needs in order to connect to the docker machine (server) [This you will need to do every time or set in your ENV vars]

   ```
   docker-machine.exe env default
   ```

   You can either install them manually or run one of the following depending on your `shell environment` (`cmd`, `bash`, `power-shell`)

   ```
   docker-machine env --shell=cmd # you need to run it manually
   docker-machine env --shell=bash > env-var-commands-tmp && . env-var-commands-tmp && rm env-var-commands-tmp
   docker-machine env --shell=powershell | Invoke-Expression
   ```

Comment: in my case i had ran : docker-machine create  default  --virtualbox-no-vtx-check

Answer (score 6):

1. Open cmd with admin rights.
2. Execute following command

   > docker-machine env --shell cmd default
3. you will receive following output

   > SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
   >
   > SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.102:2376
   >
   > SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\DBashyal.docker\machine\machines\default
   >
   > SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
   >
   > REM Run this command to configure your shell:
   >
   > REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
4. Copy the highlighted line and execute on cmd

   > > @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
5. Execute following command

   > docker ps

Comment: default is undefined. How to define it first

Comment: `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`

Answer (score 5):

I created a new machine using the below command

```
docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox vbox-test
```

Then executed the command

```
docker-machine env --shell=powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

Got it Working...

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at all the above answers and none of them worked.
Then I found out that the command has to be run on a linux command line like bash.
so try:

Type the command into the Docker bash terminal VM that comes with the docker toolbox as opposed to the windows cmd

If you have already made sure that your docker has been started

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in other answers you need to set a few environment variables.

The easiest way to do it is:

```
 @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd') DO @%i
```

This will run `docker-machine env --shell cmd` and add those environmental variables.

If you want these variables to be persistent defined them in windows ([tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).

Comment: `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Docker icon in the tray a select "Switch to Windows containers...".
You may be prompted to enable the Containers feature. Do so and reboot, again.

Answer (score 2):

To start default host in windows I know three ways given below you can use one of them.

1. Starting or restarting already created a default machine by the Docker:

   ```
   docker-machine start default
   docker-machine restart default
   ```

   Now check `docker-machine env`
2. The following environment properties need to be set:

   ```
   set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
   set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
   set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
   set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
   ```
3. To create a new machine using the following command:

**Windows 10/HyperV:**

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv default
docker-machine create -d hyperv default
```

**Mac, Linux, windows 7 & 8:**

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

Comment: default machine is already present, so you would want to give some other name

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue when I installed Docker CE for Windows Version 17.11.0-ce-rc4-win39 (14244) Channel: edge e557194 on Windows 10.

In Command/cmd windows, when I tried to run commands docker ps, docker version, docker info, the I got error like “error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.34/version” every time.

To resolved this issue,

1. I made “Hyper-V” off (Unchecked) from “Turn Windows feature on or off”, which required the OS to be restarted.
2. And after first restart, I made “Hyper-V” On (Checked), which again required the OS to be restarted.

After second restart, above docker commands started working and giving proper output.

So, turning Hyper-V **off** and then **on** resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825). It not just like [Nikesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435808/6234590) said `SwitchDaemon` could fix it directly. I think you should run this command twice to switch your daemon to your previous daemon.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
# then check the docker OS/Arch
docker version
# You may see the different OS/Arch 
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
# then you got your images and containers back
```

This command is just switch your daemon from your defualt daemon to another daemon(depends on what you set). When you switch to another daemon, the images and containers on the former daemon will disappear(but not deleted).

Comment: I ran `./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon` just once and everything was fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue on a Windows 2016 machine. Happened because the docker service wasn't started. In my case the docker service as failing with the following error

fatal: Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete C:\ProgramData\docker.pid

Deleting the C:\ProgramData\docker.pid file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

below resolved. i copied answer from another forum

I had this problem after update. After re-installing VB I switched on "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" in properties network connection.

It property switched off default in my case.
[image: `]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Professional
For me the Docker service was running but Docker still needed to be 'started'. That is, I had the setting 'Start Docker when you log in' unchecked in the Docker tray icon.

Prior to finding this out I had gone to the program folder Docker and clicked 'Docker for Windows'. After a short time the message 'Docker is running' was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was resolved after I removed `daemon.json` file in `"%programdata%\docker\config"`

The content in my `daemon.json` is the following:

```
{
  "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}
```

I created this manually as part of some testing. But after I restarted the server, I started to get the error in this question.

Comment: @Chloe the file isn't created by default, so your system couldn't find it. This is a good answer and a potential solution for people facing this issue

Comment: `>dir "%programdata%\docker\config"`
`The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0):

The error is really troubling. I hope Docker Developers do something about. It took a lot of try and error to get around. Thanks to Stackoverflow and other blogs. In my case, I am using Windows 10 Pro. I settled with DockerToolbox.exe after several failed attempts with Docker for Windows Installer.exe. Then I encountered  `An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v` . The followed these steps and the problem got solved. 
First, I went to Control Panel -> Turn Windows Features On or Off and  unchecked Hyper-V
[image]
Next, Open PowerShell as Admin:

```
docker-machine env --shell=powershell | Invoke-Expression
type bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Restarted my System. Then I launched "Docker Quickstart Terminal", then I entered this on the shell window.

```
run "Docker for Windows"
docker run hello-world
```

I it went well. Then I open Command Prompt

```
docker run hello-world
```

It gave the error: Then I entered

```
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Most of the suggestions above too are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error message after a weekend. My setup was fine before that. My config and connections looked correct. `$docker-machine restart default` fixed it for me on Windows 7

Comment: `Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, while running the command `docker-compose up`. The problem for me was, the docker service was not running. So I had to run `services.msc` and start the docker service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by run the `{DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH}start.sh` in bash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all above solutions did not resolve. Instead [zilurrane response](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825) helped.

```
    cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
    ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to Windows Containers
2. docker info
3. docker ps
4. Switch back to Linux containers
5. docker info
6. Viola!

The windows switch likely runs the missing configurations that Linux also needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue. For me I hadn't logged in to docker from the status bar. What I did was to login to docker from status bar. Once I logged in I was able to run all the commands properly.
Try logging in using your docker id and password maybe that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on my Windows 10. Find below what I did to solve it:

After installing Docker, Just restart your PC, run docker application (It may require enabling Hyper-V), then open command line and type: 
     **docker run hello-world**

Everything works fine :)

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. I searched a lot. I checked many things. But in the end, the solution that solved my problem was the following solution.

System Environment:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Windows engine in Docker
- Docker version 20.10.21

Solution

> disabled IP6
> And
> Restarted the service and application