# Unable to Connect to Tensorflow Jupyter Notebook in windows 10

Tags: docker, tensorflow, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

I am getting following error message whenever I try to fire up my jupyter notebook for tensorflow.

**Browser Error**

[image]

**Following is my status of docker in which I have got**

1. Docker machines running
2. Docker Images Downloaded

[image]

**I used Docker image ID to run it in docker**

[image]

I wonder why still my jupyter notebook is NOT getting fired although it is running properly in bash?

**Updates(Setting in VirtualBox)**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start tensorflow docker jupyter notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636925/how-do-i-start-tensorflow-docker-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: I tried the link you mentioned but it starts downloading image by scratch.

Comment: Did you set up the ports in the VirtualBox settings?

Comment: yes I did that and I have also updated.

Comment: try running it from a normal Windows command prompt instead of mingw

Comment: you mean running "docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow ./run_jupyter.sh
" from cmd?

Comment: yes that's what I mean

Comment: I tried running it from cmd but It gave error "docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified..
See 'docker run --help'."

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527888/docker-commands-fails-in-windows

Comment: I got it right now.......thank you very much indeed Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the container does not expose a port. You need to explicitly map the port to the host operating system:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -t -i b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow ./run_jupyter.sh`
```