# How can I configure com.spotify.dockerfile-maven-plugin to run on Docker Toolbox?

Tags: maven, docker, docker-maven-plugin

I started out using the [com.spotify.docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin), but it's wiki on GitHub says to switch to [com.spotify.dockerfile-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven). However in the first plugin I'm able to specify the Docker Host, but I can't figure out how to it with the latter.

My machine runs Windows 7 with Docker toolbox, so there is no Docker Daemon on localhost.

The documentation on the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` does not seem to explain how to do this.

- At first the maven output stated that it was trying to connect to localhost:2375.
- I've changed port forwarding in virtual box to forward 127.0.0.1:2375 to 2376 on the docker machine. This did not seem to work.
- I've followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527888/docker-commands-fails-in-windows) instructions:

  ```
  set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
  set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
  set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
  set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
  ```
- I've set DOCKER_HOST environment variable and checked my docker machine output:

  ```
  $ docker-machine.exe ls
  NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
  default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.06.1-ce
  ```

  This results in the maven output that tries to connect to the docker-machine on 192.168.99.100:2376 and failing when the machine is **not** running.
  This results in a different output when the machine is actually running (which is confirmed by wget, the file is empty):

  ```
  Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
  ```

  More output:

  ```
  [INFO] --- dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.4:build (default) @ botlek-server ---
  [INFO] Building Docker context D:\dev\projects\botleksensing\botleksensing\botlek-server
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] Image will be built as prorail/botlek-server:latest
  [INFO] 
  [WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
  org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
      at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:184)
      at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute(BuildMojo.java:105)
      at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:227)
      at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:216)
      at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
      at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
  Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate(DefaultDockerClient.java:2512)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2443)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.version(DefaultDockerClient.java:501)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.authRegistryHeader(DefaultDockerClient.java:2555)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1396)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1365)
      at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:177)
      ... 26 more
  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
      at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2441)
      ... 31 more
  Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
      at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:481)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run(ApacheConnector.java:491)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
      at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:487)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run(ClientRuntime.java:178)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:340)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run(ClientRuntime.java:210)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
      ... 21 more
  Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
      at         org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:151)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
      at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
      at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
      at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
      at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
      at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
      ... 23 more
  [INFO] Building Docker context D:\dev\projects\botleksensing\botleksensing\botlek-server
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] Image will be built as prorail/botlek-server:latest
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------        -------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 5.087 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-19T14:29:03+02:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/602M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.4:build (default) on project botlek-server: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the toolbox completely and installing the latest version (I'm on v17.07.0-ce now, I believe I was v17.05.0-ce before).

I also kept the environment variables described in the question (e.g. *DOCKER_HOST=192.168.99.100:2376*).

**Note** I ran into some issues with virtualbox since the Docker Toolbox installation removed the `virtualbox.msi` which was registered as the source of installation. To work around this I downloaded the installer ([here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-5.1#v20)) and used a variation on [the following command](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=40597) to extract the msi.

```
VirtualBox-4.0.4-70112-Win.exe -extract -path c:\temp
```

I had to rename the `.msi` file to `virtualbox.msi` and then I could remove the old version.