# Why am I getting error on running docker ps command

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-engine

I have installed docker version 20.10.7 on my Windows 10 machine. But when I run `docker ps` command I am getting the following error:

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: is your docker daemon running? Like mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: @RafaelRocha I have opened the docker desktop app. Is it necessary to sign in to get docker daemon working?!

Comment: **Docker Installation** just restart your windows machine and wait for docker to bootup it hasn't started running.. i am assuming you followed the docker setup process correctly.

Comment: @RafaelRocha Signing in is not required unless you want to save images to dockerhub. Is the whale icon in the task bar with containers on it or is it empty? If empty start the docker desktop application

Comment: As of Aug 31, Docker Desktop has a paid model for enterprise, therefore may require login https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that docker desktop is not running in the background.

Start > Docker Desktop (open).

Edit:
The following environment properties need to be set:

```
 set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default
 set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
 set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
 set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

Comment: I have opened the docker desktop app. Is it necessary to sign in to get docker daemon working?!

Comment: Most probably the error is because of the docker desktop not running in background. Could you please check by running 'docker' command instead?

Comment: 'docker' command is running. But when i run 'docker ps' command it is showing error

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the steps to add docker path to environment variables, Try to follow them and tell if it helps.

Comment: Anyways, This question is already answered here. Please have a look "Docker commands fails (in Windows) - Stack Overflow" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527888/docker-commands-fails-in-windows

Comment: Do I need to run these commands in cmd prompt?

Comment: Yes, You'll have to run it in command prompt.

Comment: I ran the commands specified and after running- >set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\shweta\.docker\machine\machines\default. But i am getting error- unable to resolve docker endpoint: open C:\Users\shweta\.docker\machine\machines\default\ca.pem: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Specify the path to the directory comprising the files `cert.pem, key.pem, ca-key.pem` 
These files should be in your docker installation directory.

Comment: Docker Desktop is not the same as Docker Machine and those variables aren't used by HyperV